# Adobe Acrobat PDF Javascript Detect Language

Tags: pdf

I'm sorry if I'm using the wrong forum, but I'm not sure where else to turn.

I'm trying to add javascript to a PDF file, in the Document JavaScripts. Usually we create two documents, one in English and the other in French. Recently, I figured out how to add layers to a PDF file, then I created a button to switch between layers. Now, I discovered that if you add a JS in the Document JavaScripts section of the PDF, without the function tags, it will run the script when the PDF opens.
So, what I would like to do is run a script when the document opens to detect the user's windows language, then display the English or French layer based on their windows language setting.
So far I've been able to create a popup to with the app.alert, to test out my code, but I can't find anything (that works) to detect the user's language.

```
var x = navigator.language;
app.alert({cMsg: x, Title:"Demo Title"});
enter code here
```

Also tried:

```
var x = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
app.alert({cMsg: x, Title:"Demo Title"});
```

I've tried various combinations of "navigator.language", "navigator.languages", navigator.systemLanguages", navigator.userLanguage". I know that the app.alert works because, I've replaced the "navigator.languages" with a text, and the popup works and displays the x value.
Lastly, I can't seem to find a way to switch layers from the script. Mostly, I've found using a button then using the built-in Actions with the mouse-up trigger, but it doesn't actually say what the syntax is to switch layers.
Any help, direction, or reading material would help.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no navigator object in Acrobat JavaScript; you might look at the app object. You should have a closer look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation.